# Same Dynamic Data coming in every column of webpage

Tags: python, django

I am doing CRUD using serializers, foreignkeys and I am trying to dynamically list the categories, sub_categories. For example  category = 9-6 wear and its subcategories are kurta, skirtset, dress, kurtaset. I want these subcategories below **only 9-6wear**

The issue is that other subcategories are also mentioning kurta,skirtset,dress and kurtaset which I dont want as shown below
[image]

I have tried for hours but without much success

below are my models

```
class Products(models.Model):
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Categories,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sub_categories = models.ForeignKey(SUBCategories,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Colors,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'media/',width_field=None,height_field=None,null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    sku_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    product_details = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    isactive = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Category(models.Model):
    #made changes to category_name for null and blank
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    category_description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    isactive = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class SUBCategories(models.Model):
    category_name = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sub_categories_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    sub_categories_description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    isactive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

below are the serializer

```
class CategoriesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Categories
        fields = "__all__"
        extra_kwargs = {'category_name': {'required': False}}

class POLLSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = "__all__"
```

below is my shoppingpage function

```
def shoppingpage(request):
    cat = Categories.objects.filter(isactive=True)
    category = CategoriesSerializer(cat,many=True)
    subcat = SUBCategories.objects.filter(isactive=True)
    subcategory = SUBCategoriesSerializer(subcat,many=True)
    return render(request,'polls/shoppingpage.html',{'category':category.data,'subcategory':subcategory.data})
```

below is my shoppingpage.html for loop part

```
{% for result in category %}
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="lynessa-listitem style-01">
                        <div class="listitem-inner">
                            <a href="/9-6wear" target="_self">
                                <h4 class="title">{{result.category_name}}</h4>
                            </a>
                            {% for ans in result.subcategory_set.all %}   
                                <ul class="listitem-list">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="/kurta" target="_self">{{ans.sub_categories_name}}</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            {% endfor %}                                      
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
                {% endfor %}
```

help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are just looping through all the subcategories for all of the categories in your template:

```
{% for result in category %}
   ...
      {% for ans in subcategory %}
```

You should change the second loop so that it only refers to related subcategories:

```
{% for ans in result.subcategory_set.all %}
```

**Edit**

Serializers aren't necessary in this example, nor is the subcategory queryset. The view can look like this:

```py
def shoppingpage(request):
   categories = Categories.objects.filter(isactive=True)
   context = {'categories': categories}
   return render(request,'polls/shoppingpage.html', context)
```

**Edit**
A lot of the errors came down to context/variable misalignment:

```py
# models.py
model Category
   ...

model Subcategory
   ...
```

```py
# views.py
context = {'categories': Category.objects.all()}
```

```html
# template
{% for category in categories %}
    {% for subcategory in category.subcategory_set.all %}
     ...
```

Comment: Hi 0sVoid, I was trying by myself and also checked out your solution , but the names of subcategories arent showing up

Comment: Try using `result.subcategories_set.all` instead - I just notice you have pluralised your models, you should name your models `Category` instead of `Categories`

Comment: I tried that as well and it didnt work.

I have changed the model 'Categories' to category

Comment: You are serializing your objects but then just rendering them in a HTML template, what is the purpose of that? I would just remove the serializers and render the queryset directly, that is probably why you can't access the model relation

Comment: I see so I only need to retrive the objects and them pass it into the dictionary adn then put it instead of using serializers right?

Comment: Correct, you only need to pass your `cat` variable into the context because you can use the reverse relationship accessor to get subcategories

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246565/discussion-between-ameya-potdar-and-0svoid).